# On the real roots of the chromatic polynomial

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, graph-theory, coloring, algebraic-graph-theory

If $\chi_G(k)$ is the chromatic polynomial of graph $G$ on $n$ vertices, we want to prove the following statements:

1. The only real root $x<1$ for $\chi_G(k)$ except for $x=0$.
2. There is no real root $x>n$ for $\chi_G(k)$.

Things that I have tried:

1. I can show that the terms of the chromatic polynomial alternate in sign. This means that there is no negative root. But still cannot handle the interval $(0,1)$.
2. By definition of the chromatic polynomial, it is obvious that there is no integer root. But hard to say something about the real roots.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question: if for some $y$ in (0, 1), we have $P(G, y)=0$, then we know $P(G\setminus e, y)= P(G/e, y)$. Since all the efficients of chromatic polynomial are integers and $\deg P(G\setminus e, x)=n$, $\deg P(G/e, x)=n-1$, we can compare the number of digits after demical and conclude that it is impossible.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How we can compare decimals when $y$ is irrational?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but I have no intuitive proof for irrational y. Maybe you can refer to <W. T. Tutte, Chromials>, where the proof is by induction on connected graphs.

Comment: And you can refer to http://web.cs.elte.hu/blobs/diplomamunkak/mat/2009/hubai_tamas.pdf for many properties about chromatic polynomials, including Question 1 and 2.